# how to create a variable matrix depending on an index

Tags: numpy, scipy

I am trying to create the following type of matrix using `scipy or numpy`.

```
A_1 = diag(0.5, 0, 0, ...., 0)
A_k = diag(0,0, ..., 1, 0, 0, ....,0) for each 1 < k < N
A_N = diag(0, 0, ...., 0, 0.5)
```

Essentially `A_k`s are a series of  a diagonal matrices such that each `A_k`  has a 1 in the kth position of the diagonal for 1 < k < N and `A_1` is a diagonal matrix with 0.5 in the (1,1) position zeros everywhere else and `A_N` is a diagonal matrix with 0.5 in the (N,N) position and zeros everywhere else.

I know I can use the sparse matrices in `scipy` and I know how to create each individual matrix. But how do I create the entire series of matrices as a  function that can be called depending on `k`?

More explicitly for N = 4.

```
A_1 = diag(0.5, 0, 0, 0)
A_2 = diag(0, 1, 0, 0)
A_3 = diag(0, 0, 1, 0)
A_4 = diag(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
```

Comment: Aren't each of `A_1` etc. 2D arrays each? Maybe show us the expected o/p for N= 4 or something?

Comment: Yes, they are. I added the matrices explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach -

```
def diag_ndarray(N):
    # Initialize o/p array
    out = np.zeros((N,N,N))

    # Get n-dimensional indices for assigning non-zero values
    idx = np.tile(np.arange(N),3).reshape(3,-1)

    # Setup non-zero values and assign with subscripted indexing
    out[tuple(idx)] = np.hstack((0.5,[1]*(N-2),0.5))
    return out
```

A simpler version -

```
def diag_ndarray_v2(N):
    out = np.zeros((N,N,N))
    r = np.arange(N)
    out[r,r,r] = np.hstack((0.5,[1]*(N-2),0.5))
    return out
```

A bit more shorter version with linear indices -

```
def diag_ndarray_v3(N):
    out = np.zeros((N,N,N))
    out.ravel()[np.arange(N)*(1+N*(N+1))] = np.hstack((0.5,[1]*(N-2),0.5))
    return out
```

Sample run -

```
In [128]: diag_ndarray(N=4)
Out[128]: 
array([[[ 0.5,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]],

       [[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]],

       [[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0. ,  1. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]],

       [[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
        [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.5]]])
```

Comment: To make it sparse can I start out with a `lil` of the right size as suggested earlier?

Comment: @JackDawkins Don't think you can represent with any  sparse matrices, as neither support 3D arrays, which is the desired output here.

Answer (score 1):

```
A_k = np.zeros((n,n))
A_k[k,k] =1
```

or `=.5` if `k==0` or `k==n-1`

Or am I missing some nuance?

To make it sparse start with a `lil` of the right size.  Though it's also easy to specify the `coo` inputs for that single diagonal value.

Comment: This doesn't create a series of matrices that I can for example sum over right?. (i.,e sum(A_k) will give me A_1 + A_2 + A_3 + .... etc. How can I extend it so?